# Is there a tumblr block to check if there are posts, like HasPages?

Tags: css, tumblr

A tumblr theme I'm developing initially will not have any blog posts and mainly consists of static content.

Is there a block like `{block:HasPages}` that I can wrap around all my post code to stop it rendering if there are no posts on the blog please?

The reason I need this is because I'm wrapping the posts in a tag with styling I don't want to be shown until there are actually posts on the page.

```
<ul id="posts">
    {block:Posts}
        <li class="post group" .....
```

The UL with ID posts has styling that isnt wanted when there are no posts. If there is no `{block:HasPosts}` block, does anyone know how to combat this issue please?

Comment: I posted an answer, but this seems like an XY question. Can you please expand on the view that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no. For all views, apart from 404, there is always at least one post.

**CSS Solution**

You could try `:empty`, but this depends on whitespace:

```
#posts:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

**Tumblr Solution**

If you know the amount of post being displayed per page, you could use the following:

```
{block:IndexPage}
{block:Posts}
{block:Post1}
<ul id="posts">
{/block:Post1}
...
{block:Post15}
</ul>
{/block:Post15}
{/block:Posts}
{/block:IndexPage}
```